# Display changes in SCSS/HTML without refreshing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sass, reload

I was wondering if it's possible that chrome will display the changes I made in my HTML structure or my SCSS/css files without refreshing the page.

I work on a file name "main.scss", and using the default sass watcher.

I see that there's an option "Auto-reload generated CSS" under "Source" in the settings, but I can't get it to work..

hope I can get an answer if that's even possible. (I know that there are some extensions)

Comment: What are you trying to do?! All changes to your HTML/CSS will be reflected in the browser window. There is no way to go around that as far as I know, in any browser. If you want to add tags but not show them yet, you could mark them as `display: none`. Once read just change the CSS to the correct value.

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this](http://www.amazeelabs.com/en/How-to-write-Sass-within-Chromes-DevTools-using-Workspaces-and-Auto-reload)?

Comment: I want to see the changes that I make on Style.scss, right as I save the file with some changes.

Comment: oh wow @ialarmedalien alarmed alien, this is great. Thanks buddy. Got one last question though. Is this possible to see the changes while the inspector is closed?

Comment: Please I would really like to know if it's possible. Cause whenever the inspect or the tab of that very specific file is not in focus, the reload wont work..